# SQL table groupby query employee table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlite, t-sql

I have a table as below and i want to group it by employee.

```
Employee    ID      AMOUNT
ABC         101     200
ABC         101     2365
ABD         222     5544
ABC         101     83013
ABD         222     6545
```

I want to see

```
Employee    id      amount
Abc         101     85578
Abd         222     12089
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This was a pretty straight forward question.  To get a better result in the future, you may want to include code you've tried so far.  That way we can point out what's wrong/missing instead of fishing for you.  This site is more about teaching and problem solving, than doing the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select employee, ID, sum(amount) as Amount
FROM TableName
group by Employee, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is `SUM()`:

```
select employee, id, sum(amount)
from yourtable
group by employee, id
```